# Problem while receving the Json Result.. Asp.net mvc 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

i am having a problem while retrieving the data coming from Json...

i am passing some values through $.ajax and i want to process that values in the controller..

please help, how can i retrieve the values in controller...

## Jquery Code

```
    var userID = @Model.User.UserID;
        var postID = @Model.Post.PostID;
        var commentBody = $('#textareaForComment').val();

$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e)
    {

        e.preventDefault();
        var postdata = 
        {
            CommentBody: commentBody,
            PostID: postID,
            UserID: userID            
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SubmittedComment","Post")',
            data: postdata,
            success: function(data) { 
                $('#showComments').html(data);
            }
        });
  });
```

now i am calling the SubmittedComment Action in the Post controller and i want to have the PostID,USerID and the CommentBody in that action and want to store it in a diff variable..

please help. thx

## controller code

```
public JsonResult SubmittedComment(string CommentBody,UserID,PostID)
        {

            var result = CommentBody // i am not able to get the value here ....

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SubmittedComment","Post")',
        // Values should be evaluated at the callback, not at page load time
        // this is not the case for UserID and PostID, but for CommentBody it is
        data: {
          UserID: @Model.User.UserID,
          PostID: @Model.Post.PostID,
          CommentBody: $('#textareaForComment').val()
        },
        success: function(data) { 
            // Controller action returns data in Json format, so .html() makes no sence here.
            // Change action to return html markup via PartialView or change this function to
            // parse Json. Also, returning Json via GET request is forbidden by default by ASP.NET MVC (just in case you don't know
            $('#showComments').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false; // Equals to e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that CommentBody should be evaluated in the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery ajax call is not performing an `HTTP POST`.

EDIT: Note that you should also be evaluating `$('#textareaForComment').val()` in your button click event, as Artem pointed out.

Add the option `type: 'POST'` to your call:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var postdata = 
    {
        CommentBody: $('#textareaForComment').val(),
        PostID: postID,
        UserID: userID            
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SubmittedComment","Post")',
        data: postdata,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) { 
            $('#showComments').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively, use the `post()` function:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("SubmittedComment","Post")',
    postdata, 
    success: function(data) { 
        $('#showComments').html(data);
    }
);
```

You will also want to add the `[HttpPost]` attribute to your controller action to restrict the exucution of the method to HTTP POST only:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmittedComment(string CommentBody, int UserID, int PostID)
{
    // ... snip ...
}
```

Comment: got it... i completely forgot to put the type in $.ajax call...thx for pointing it out...